# Unable to autenticate in OAUTH2.0

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, service-accounts

I am trying to test a JSON credentials in google OAUTH 2.0

But it gives me error 401, the service account has access to the google sdk admin, the project id was added to domain delegation.
Any ideas.

I am trying to test some OAUTH credentials to verify that the API is being accessed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwJpY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oauth2 playground works with Oauth2 clients installed and web.

Service account authorization is different flow playground doesn't support that flow. Create a new client either installed or web.